# What is the prefered approach for this? (distribution)

Tags: probability-distributions

Let's say I want to have a list of random numbers that follow a distribution. All random numbers should be between 0 and 100, and the mean is variable but doesn't change while we generate the randoms.

Behavior:

- The mean = 50, there's the same number of randoms on the two sides of the mean
- The mean = 25, there's more randoms on the right of the mean than there's on its left
- The mean = 75, there's more randoms on the left of the mean than there's on its right

But all the random numbers are between 0 and 100, always. I thought about normal distribution but there's no minimal or maximal value, and it's too symmetric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binomial distribution? 100 independent yes/no. Probability p for yes gives mean 100p.